# Call MS SQL Function from JPA

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have a function in MS SQL like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FOO (@param1 int,@param2 int)
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN (SELECT a, b, c
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE p = @param1
              AND (@param2 IS NULL
                OR x = @param2));
```

And a Entity Class like:

```
    @Entity
    @SqlResultSetMappings=(value={
       @SqlResultSetMapping(
          name="fooMapping"
          classes=@ConstructorResult(
             targetClass=Foo.class,
             columns= {
                @ColumnResult(name="a", type=Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="b", type=Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="c", type=Long.class)}
          )
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name="getFoos",
  query="CALL FOO(:param1, :param2) ORDER BY c",
  resultSetMappings="fooMapping",
  callable=true)
public class Foo {
   ...
}
```

When I try to call the function with:

```
TypedQuery<Foo> query = em.createNamedQuery("getFoos", Foo.class);
query.setParameter("param1", param1);
query.setParameter("param2", null);
List<Foo> result = query.getResultList();
```

Then I get SQLServerException:

> Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

What do I do wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You're missing a data type for `@param2`.

Comment: @param2 is set to NULL. I get the same Exception when I set @param2=123L.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a data type: `CREATE FUNCTION FOO (@param1 int,@param2)` Between `@Param2` and the right parenthesis(`)`) there needs to be a datatype.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to set '@param2' to int in the example code above. But '@param2' has type int

Comment: If you get some exception then you can easily post the stack trace, and the actual SQL invoked (from the JPA providers log). aka debugging

Comment: Hibernate can't call function? https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-sql-server-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/